# Creating IFRAME with JS and show anywhere on the page

Tags: javascript, iframe

How can I create an IFRAME with JavaScript and give as src any of my pages, also I need to give parameters to the src so data will be returned according to these parameters.
For example this is my src link : http://www.mysite.com/pages/exportdata.aspx?category=game and this will go to my db and return gamenames under the game category.

Then I will show this iframe anywhere on the page which does not itself have access to my database.

Comment: so what exactly is the question here? Is it about creating the iFrame or accessing the database

Answer (score 1):

You mean

```
window.onload=function() {
  var cat = "game";
  var fr = document.createElement("iframe");
  fr.width="400";
  fr.height="500";
  fr.src="http://www.mysite.com/pages/exportdata.aspx?category="+cat;
  document.getElementById('frameContainer').appendChild(fr);
}
```

Comment: thank you , this is mean  "document.getElementById('frameContainer') " div that in my page?

Comment: Yes, `<div id="frameContainer"></div>` will get the iframe

Comment: thats easy ,  :) i can set position of the IFRAME any place of the page that i want with js when creating IFRAME?

Comment: No. Then you will have to make it position:absolute, but then it will overlay other stuff

Comment: I do not understand your question

Comment: i want search topic like this in the google , but i can't find right keyword in english.